# Parse error: syntax error within the If statement

Tags: php

So if I have been trying to create an If statement in my HTML PHP file where it should display as "N/A" if the `'Workshop_Contact'=="0"`.

I've tried some ways but seems like I couldn't find the solution

Here is the line code:

```
<h4 class="card-title text-danger">Contact:
  <?=
      if ($row['Workshop_Contact']==0){
         echo "N/A";
      }
      else{
         echo "0" . $row['Workshop_Contact'];
      }
  ?>
</h4>
```

Comment: Replace `<?=` with `<?`

Comment: `<?=` is for echo keyword. Remove the `=` or better use `<?php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use a ternary

```html
<h4 class="card-title text-danger">
  Contact: <?= $row['Workshop_Contact'] == 0 ? 'N/A' : '0' . $row['Workshop_Contact'] ?>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

The open tag `<?=` is used to print out data. Your code does not return any data for this tag to print. In short, you cannot use both `<?=` and `echo` inside.

The tags used by PHP are:

- `<?` short open tag (must be enabled in config), replaces `<?php`
- `<?=` print tag, replaces `<?php echo`
- `<?php` the standard PHP opening tag
- `?>` closing tag.

Here are some examples:

```php
<?
   if ($row['Workshop_Contact'] == 0)
      echo "N/A";
   else
      echo "0" . $row['Workshop_Contact'];
?>
```

```php
<?= "1 + 1 = " . 1 + 1 ?>
```

```php
<?= condition ? "condition is 'true'" : "the condition is 'false'" ?>
```

```php
<?php
   echo "Hello world";
?>
```